# Authenticated REST Web services integration from Java

Tags: java, web-services, authentication, liferay, peoplesoft

We are working on a POC to integration from a custom Java application to integrate to the Student PeopleSoft authenticated/secure REST web services. The Liferay Portal and Student Peoplesoft are integrated with the Oracle IdM SSO on the Web tier.

We are developing server side Java plugin code (Liferay) to connect to the PeopleSoft authenticated/secure REST web services. The PeopleSoft authenticated/secure REST web services need a username / password or a token in the basic authorization headers for the connection to be successful.

Has anyone done this before?

The challenge we are running into is that java code does not have access to the credentials for the student or a valid token for the backend PIA where the web services are hosted on the Integration Broker.

Any insight on this would be very valuable.

**Background on Platform/architecture:**

**Java:** Liferay Portal as the Java platform. Domain – example.liferay.com. We are hoping to develop a Liferay Java Portlet plugin. However, this could be any Java platform/application. Integrated to Oracle IdM SSO

**ERP:** Student PeopleSoft – authenticated REST web services hosted on a separate backend PIA not integrated to the Oracle IdM SSO. Integrated to Oracle IdM SSO on another Web facing PIA. Domains - student.frontend.com, student.backend.com.

**SSO:** Oracle IdM

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to resolve this issue by creating a new instance of **Liferay** with the same parent level domain as **Student PeopleSoft** system and change the Oracle IdM login flow to sure a student was always logged in to the **PeopleSoft** system first.

This approach allowed us to access the cookies and pass the correct values to the web services regardless of the web services being hosted on different back-end PIA.

More details posted on [PeopleSoft screens in an iFrame post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29374351/1678967)