# Peoplesoft screens in an iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe, liferay, single-sign-on, peoplesoft

Has anyone successfully integrated Peoplesoft screens or navigation via an iFrame in a third party app like Liferay or uPortal?

We are trying to integrate Liferay Portal as a web front end and consume some of the PeopleSoft screens in an iFrame portlet. Both the Liferay Portal and Peoplsoft systems are on different top level domains. We are using Oracle Single Sign On on bot the applications. We have a couple of issues with this.

- The screens display in the iFrame - however, the JavaScript on the PeopleSoft does not execute and keeps spinning. In Chrome devtools console, there is the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getStoredData' of undefinedPT_PAGESCRIPT_win0_MIN_1.jsp

- If not already signed in to the PeopleSoft system via SSO - the Login page pops out of the iFrame on IE browsers. To clarify based on comments below, the SSO happens for the first app like Liferay, however the user didnot try to go the second app PeopleSoft yet. So the SSO cookies for the second app (PeopleSoft) are not yet in the session. So when we access the page with the iFrame containing the Peoplesoft page, it pops out of the frame in IE trying to establish SSO session and cookies with PeopleSoft.

Has anyone been able to solve any of these issues?

Any insight would be much appreciated. I can provide more details if needed.

Thanks!

Edited for clarification based on comments below.

Comment: Can you check in developer tools in chrome as to what error you get in console for the 1st point. And 2nd point seems obvious, you should be signed-in through SSO before seeing the pages of peoplesoft, or is there something else you want to do? Thanks

Comment: 1- I get a error in the console "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getStoredData' of undefinedPT_PAGESCRIPT_win0_MIN_1.jsp" For 2, the SSO happens for the first app like Liferay, however the user did try to go the second app Peoplesoft yet, so the SSO cookies are not yet in the session. So when we access the page with the iFrame containing the Peoplesoft page, it pops out of the frame in IE trying to establish SSO session and cookies with PeopleSoft. Hope this makes sense. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: The same page works fine outside the iframe?

Comment: Yes, the page works fine outside the iFrame.

Comment: without the iFrame does the liferay page load without any js errors?

Comment: Yes, without the iFrame the Liferay page loads without any JS errors. Retyping my comment above to fix a typo as for some reason I can't edit it. -- For 2, the SSO happens for the first app like Liferay, however the user didnot try to go the second app Peoplesoft yet, so the SSO cookies are not yet in the session. So when we access the page with the iFrame containing the Peoplesoft page, it pops out of the frame in IE trying to establish SSO session and cookies with PeopleSoft. Hope this makes sense. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: I am not sure why using SSO, still people-soft would pop-out. I have SSO and an application running other than liferay inside an iframe and it logs in fine even when I am visiting the application only through the iframe the first time. Can you provide a screenshot or something as to what happens? Also I think the domain within the iframe might be different due to which the javascripts are not being loaded can you check in different browser's developer tools what error they give also check chrome's Network panel if there is any js blocked from loading?

Comment: Yes, the java script errors are occuring because of the different domains. Thanks to Prakash. In my case Liferay is consuming Peoplesoft in an iFrame. I am not sure how to provide a screen shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have been able to resolve the above 2 issues.

- First, we created a new instance of the portal in the same parent domain as the PeopleSoft domain and ensured both were using SSL so the protocol matched. This resolved the cross domain JS errors
- Second, we changed our Oracle IdM SSO login flow to always redirect to a new PeopleSoft PIA which redirects back to Liferay's original URL. This ensures there is a valid PeopleSoft session and prevents iFrame popouts along with other integration issues. There is a lot of changes and work done by our team on this around related use cases(deep links, session timeouts) and flows. I'd be happy to post more details if anyone is proceeding down the same path.

Thanks for all the comments which helped us dig in the right direction. We also got feedback from other Liferay and PeoplesSoft customers who followed similar approaches.